# Linear Approximations and Differentials

Tags: calculus

I'm a bit confused on how to start this problem and was hoping someone could help:

> Use linear approximation, i.e. the tangent line, to approximate
>   $\,1/0.254\,$ as follows:
>   Let $\,f\left(x\right) = 1/x\,$ and find the equation of the
>   tangent line to $\,f\left(x\right)\,$  at a "nice" point near $\,0.254$. Then use this to approximate $\,1/0.254$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you find the tangent line to $f$ at an arbitrary $x$?

Comment: So I would choose an arbitrary number for x to solve?

Comment: No. You said you didn't know how to start. The first thing you need to do is calculate the equation for the tangent line at a point $x$ on that curve. I hope the one to use is obvious.

Comment: And rather than "choosing an arbitrary number for x", there is  rather obvious number close to 0.254 such that 1/x is simple.